# innerHTML += 'foobar' in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to append instead of delete the inner HTML. I have been using `element.innerHTML+= 'foobar'` to achieve this but i am not learning to use jQuery and I have seen the `$().HTML('')` call but that erases my connect instead of appending. How do i get it to append?

Comment: How do you *append* html with jQuery? well, you'd use the *append* method. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 6):

> I am trying to *append* instead of delete the inner HTML...

Have you tried using [*append*](http://api.jquery.com/append/)?

```
$("#someDiv").append("foobar");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jcx8j/

Answer (score 1):

Using the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function:

```
$('#myid').append("<p>test</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google could have solved this for you [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('.inner').append('<p>Test</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

with append you can do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#me').click(function(){
      $('#more').append('MORE!!')
   });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/edamup/1/edit